# Having problems with strings, program crashing

Tags: c, windows, c-strings

I am a newbie trying to learn calling `strings`. So here is a program I wrote and I'm trying to achieve a program that displays all characters of a name one per line. This program compiles successfully but after entering the name, the program crashes. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks very much !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{    
  char s;

  printf("Enter name\n");
  scanf("%c", s);

  int i;
  for( i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++);
  printf("%c, s[i]");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", s);` --> `scanf("%c", &s);`

Comment: Wait...stop...really? a _string_ in a `char`?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues:

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{    
  char s[100];     // array of 100 chars

  printf("Enter name\n");
  scanf("%s", s);  // read name from user into s array

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    printf("%c", s[i]);    

  return 0;
}
```

Advanced topic:

This line:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
```

although correct, is inefficient.

Following code is better:

```
int len = strlen(s);

for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

Finding out why is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you !

Can you tell me what exactly is happening here

int len = strlen(s);

for (i = 0; i < len; i++)

Comment: @theweeknd Hint: if `s` contains a string of length 10000, how many times will `strlen` be called with your code ? And how many times will it be called with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your program. First you have only allocated memory for a single `char`, but you want to store a name into it (which consists of multiple `chars`).

Furthermore, you have multiple syntax errors such as `;` after the for loop and a misplaced `"` in the `printf` call.

If I understood it correctly you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s[200];

  printf("Enter name\n");
  scanf("%s", &s);

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    printf("%c\n", s[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it, with explanations in comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s[] = {"\0"}; //s should be a char array type, it needs explicit size or initialization
  printf("Enter name\n");
  scanf("%s", s);    //format specifier must match data type
  int len = strlen(s);
  for( int i = 0; i < len; i++)
      printf("%c\n", s[i]);//format specifier must match data type
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks - hope this looks better